# What function describes this behavior?

Tags: functions, polynomials

On Steam, the $XP$ required to level up increases every $10$ levels. $A_{0} = 100XP$

Level $1$ requires $100 XP$, level $2$ requires $200 XP$, etc. until level $10$ which requires $1000$ *total* $XP$ (it's only $100 XP$ from levels $9$ to $10$)

Once we get to level $10$, the increase per level is $200 XP$. So level $11$ requires $1200$ total, level $12$ requires $1400$ total, etc.

This continues on forever.

$F(L) := $ total $XP$ required for level $L$.

What is $F(L)$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be the level. Let $a = \lfloor \frac{N}{10} \rfloor$, and $b = N - 10 a$. For example, if $N = 34$, then $a = 3$ and $b = 4$.

Then the "total XP" needed to reach level $N$ is $500 a (a + 1) + 100 (a + 1) b = 100 (a + 1) (5 a + b)$, as can be checked.